# Turtlebot doesn't stop after killing the velocity command

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I am running two turtlebots  (kobuki) with gazebo1.9 and I provided command velocities to each turtlebot using “rostopic pub” command. I noticed that turtlebot keep moving after I killed the command velocity using “Control tab  +c”.
I am wondering if this anomaly is due to the inertia values for my turtlebot wheels or something else
Thanks for any help with this issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6117/turtlebot-doesn%27t-stop-after-killing-the-velocity-command/) by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2014-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try to send a 0 velocity command.

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'
```

Not sure if this is the right command but give it a try or replace it with the right one and let me know.

Hope that works.

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) with karma: 349 on 2014-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-05-05**:
Thanks Ffurrer. I sent a 0 velocity command and the turtlebot stopped. Somebody mentioned the gazebo plugin might not have a timeout on incoming commands when they stop being published it may continue to execute the last received command.

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-05-05**:
Your tip worked for me. Thanks a lot!!